# Property 'then' does not exist on type 'ComponentFactory<SpinnerComponent>'

Tags: angular

In below Angular version `2.2.0`, I am getting below error at line,

Plunker Link,

http://plnkr.co/edit/f6GBBQan7z4I9K1qBZOi?p=preview

```
spinnerRef.then((factory: ComponentFactory<any>) => {
```

**Error, Property 'then' does not exist on type 'ComponentFactory'**

What could be reason for this and the solution, please suggest. Thanks!

```
import { Injectable, ApplicationRef, ViewContainerRef, Component, ComponentRef, ComponentFactoryResolver, ComponentFactory, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

import { SpinnerComponent } from '../components/blockui/blockui.component';


@Injectable()
export class SpinnerService {
    spinnerComp: ComponentRef<any>;

    constructor(private _appRef: ApplicationRef, private _resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
    }

    public start() {
        let elementRef: ViewContainerRef = (<any>this._appRef)['_rootComponents'][0].location;

        return this.startInside(elementRef, null);
    }

    public startInside(elementRef: ViewContainerRef, anchorName: string) {

        let spinnerRef = this._resolver.resolveComponentFactory(SpinnerComponent);

        spinnerRef.then((factory: ComponentFactory<any>) => {
            this.spinnerComp = elementRef.createComponent(factory)
        });
    }

    public stop() {
        if (this.spinnerComp) {
            this.spinnerComp.destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
resolveComponentFactory(component: Type<T>) : ComponentFactory<T>
```

returns a `ComponentFactory<T>` not a `Promise<ComponentFactory<T>>` - it's not async.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ComponentFactoryResolver-class.html

```
public startInside(elementRef: ViewContainerRef, anchorName: string) {
    let factory = this._resolver.resolveComponentFactory(SpinnerComponent);
    this.spinnerComp = elementRef.createComponent(factory);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now error is remove, but when I am running I m getting error,  "No component factory found for SpinnerComponent"

Comment: You probably didn't add `SpinnerComponent` to `@NgModule({entryComponents: [SpinnerComponent], ...})` That's required for all dynamically added components.

Comment: I put under @ declaration, when I m trying to put under entryComponents, it's throws error "Component SpinnerComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module. ; Zone: <root> ; Task:"

Comment: Are you add `SpinnerComponent` statically as well (somewhere in your app) or is above code the only place where you're using it? If you are adding it statically as well you need to add it to both `declarations` and `entryComponents`.

Comment: Thanks, but a new error "elementRef.createComponent is not a function"

Comment: I don't know but your approach `(<any>this._appRef)['_rootComponents']` is not officially supported. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9293#issuecomment-261329089 seems to use a similar approach, perhaps you find there something that helps. An alternative approach that involves the root component is https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6446#issuecomment-248912305

Comment: I added all the code in this punker link, http://plnkr.co/edit/f6GBBQan7z4I9K1qBZOi?p=preview

Comment: `(<any>this._appRef)['_rootComponents'][0]` seems to return an `ElementRef` instead of a `ViewContainerRef`. Sorry, I can't help you here. I fixed several other issues in the Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/UEEQQRzX7RIkSO49rCHu?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, I will look this issue.